# How to Display an Image on mouseover in Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

Hi guys i need some help on how to code in as3 to display an image on mouseover over a button. I have this for now actually. I need the buttons to show some image in the screen on doing mouse over. . . .  . . . .  .

```
var centerX:Number = 330;
var centerY:Number = 130;
var radiusX:Number = 250;
var radiusY:Number = 50;
var speed:Number = 0.1;
var farthestFade:Number = 0.2;
var farthestSize:Number = 1;
var minSpeed:Number = -0.10;
var maxSpeed:Number = 0.10;
var rangeSpeed:Number = maxSpeed - minSpeed;
var minY:Number = centerY - radiusY;
var maxY:Number = centerY + radiusY;
var rangeY:Number = maxY - minY;
var minScale:Number = 0.3;
var maxScale:Number = 0.7;
var rangeScale:Number = maxScale - minScale;
var itemArray:Array = new Array();



var image1MC:image1 = new image1();
itemArray.push(image1MC);
image1MC.targetURL = "http://www.gmail.com";


var image2MC:image2 = new image2();
itemArray.push(image2MC);
image2MC.targetURL = "http://www.gmail.com";

var image3MC:image3 = new image3();
itemArray.push(image3MC);
image3MC.targetURL = "http://www.twitter.com";

var image4MC:image4 = new image4();
itemArray.push(image4MC);
image4MC.targetURL = "http://www.facebook.com";

var image5MC:image5 = new image5();
itemArray.push(image5MC);
image5MC.targetURL = "http://www.linkedin.com";

var image6MC:image6 = new image6();
itemArray.push(image6MC);
image6MC.targetURL = "http://www.microsoft.com";

var image7MC:image7 = new image7();
itemArray.push(image7MC);
image7MC.targetURL = "http://www.irctc.co.in";

var image8MC:image8 = new image8();
itemArray.push(image8MC);
image8MC.targetURL = "http://www.yahoo.com";

var canvas:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(canvas);

for (var i:Number = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++)
{
    canvas.addChild(itemArray[i]);
    itemArray[i].buttonMode = true;
    itemArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goToURL);
    itemArray[i].itemAngle = Math.PI * 2 / itemArray.length * i;
    itemArray[i].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animate);
}

function goToURL(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest(e.currentTarget.targetURL);
    navigateToURL(req);
}

function animate(e:Event):void
{
    speed = mouseX / stage.stageWidth * rangeSpeed + minSpeed;
    e.currentTarget.x = Math.cos(e.currentTarget.itemAngle) * radiusX + centerX;
    e.currentTarget.y = Math.sin(e.currentTarget.itemAngle) * radiusY + centerY;
    e.currentTarget.itemAngle += speed;
    itemArray.sortOn("y");

    for(var i:Number = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++)
    {
        canvas.setChildIndex(itemArray[i], i);
        var pct:Number = (itemArray[i].y - minY) / rangeY;
        var scale:Number = pct * rangeScale + minScale;
        itemArray[i].scaleX = itemArray[i].scaleY = scale;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe your specific problems that you need help with, and show what you've already tried and researched, as it stands, this is not a question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask | http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Where do you want to show the image? Is the image preloaded / on stage? Do you want to show the image on the button? In order to get help please add substantial context of things which you have tried. Hope you take this as a positive feedback. Thanks.

Comment: I have my buttons in stage. And i have some codes written to make the buttons rotate like a carousel. Now what i need is, if i make a mouse over a button, it should describe about it as other image or a text.

Comment: @Venki Do you have any kind of mapping which maps each buttons to a specific image or text?

Comment: no its not mapped each other, each button describes diffrent images or texts.

Comment: @venki Okay, so you need code to show image/text in a specific area on hovering of button. Correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: yes. .  ur right. . but the button is on the stage. its not preloaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you have your buttons on stage.

```
var btn:Button;
for(var i=0; i<this.numChildren; i++){
  var btn = this.getChildAt(i) as Button;
  if(btn){
    btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOverHandler);
    btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, mouseOutHandler);
  }
}
function mouseOverHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{
  // Add code to show any image / text
}
function mouseOutHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{
  // Add code to remove any image / text
}
```

Updated: 23-09-2013 - solution as per your updated question.

```
....
// Hover container sprite
var hContainer:Sprite = new Sprite;
addChildAt(hContainer, 0);

for (var i:Number = 0; i < itemArray.length; i++)
{
    ...
    // Add mouser over handler
    itemArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, mouseOverHandler);
    ...
}

/**
* MouseOver Listener
* @param e MouseEvent
*/
function mouseOverHandler(e:MouseEvent):void{
    var url:String = e.currentTarget.targetURL as String;
    addHoverImage(url);
}

/**
* Add hover image
* @param url String 
*/
function addHoverImage(url:String):void{
    if(hContainer.numChildren)
        hContainer.removeChildAt(0);
    var loader:Loader = new Loader();
    hContainer.addChild(loader);
    loader.load(new URLRequest(url));
}
...
```

Please find the detailed solution at [gist url](https://gist.github.com/samarpanda/6671626)

---

Some comments to improve your code structure and approach.

- Ideally i would prefer using as3 class structure rather than adding all my codes to Flash IDE timeline.
- Please don't try to repeat yourself i.e

-

```
//Problem in this block of code as you have repeated lot of times.
var image1MC:image1 = new image1();
itemArray.push(image1MC);
image1MC.targetURL = "tab.png"

// Better approach could be try adding a class and pass require parameters.
var image1MC:ImageClass = new ImageClass("tab.png");
addChild(image1MC);
```

Comment: I have my code attached above. Actually its a part of a code. Hope you can understand if you have a look at it. Actually the above code links you to other page. But i need the buttons to display image when mouseover is done.

Comment: As per your code. I don't think you are doing it right. As you are trying to instantiate image1, image2 and so on. You should create an Image Class. Instantiate that and set property accordingly.

As per your code i can only figure out that you are trying to make an array of images with target url links. But its not clear where are your buttons. And how do you want to assign listeners i.e mouse events.

Comment: check my full code now and try for help. i had sent you request in gmail too samar. . try out. And my images are not on stage. I am loading it from library.

Comment: @Venki You can share your code using github.com / bitbucket.org. Please submit the repository link here. So i can have a look.

Comment: I have my full code displayed above now. ping me on gmail if your available there. will send you my file.

Answer (score 0):

Simple code :

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("imgurl.png"));
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER , onOver);
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT , onOut);

loader.y = button.y+button.height;

function onOver(e:MouseEvent):void {
    addChild(loader);
}
function onOut(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if(loader.parent){
        removeChild(loader);
    }
}
```

Comment: turbosqel your code worked fine.But I have my buttons on stage and if i make mouse over those buttons i need some images to get displayed.